# How do you make QT threads in python for pyqt?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I see discussion about qt threads vs python threads but how do you create and call qt threads in python?  how do you give it access to your functions in another thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a good, fully worked-out example [here](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots).

Comment: In this example, it doesn't seem to open up the threads in the if __name__ == '__main__' portion fo the code?  Why is htis?

Comment: Because it uses the `Worker` custom subclass of `QtThread` -- it's instantiated and activated at need, quite independently of whether the module is imported or run as a script, so why should the `if __name__` &c section have anything to do with the case?!

Comment: So is this special subclass dealing with all of the signals/slots for me?  So I don't need to manually deal with the threading of the gui versus my functional code?  My apologise for the questions :)

Comment: @jim, have you tried the long example I've pointed you to and the code in it? It does a good job _showing_ QThread's possibilites and limitations. For reference info, that does a good job of _telling_ you about it, see http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html and all links from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/threads.html .